# What's the proper way of filtering data fetched from REST?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I've written for the beginning basic, very simple app in Android Studio which just fetches data from various REST methods and presents them in a table.

However, I would like to extend the functionality and offer user possibility of filtering data, for example, to get data from a different time. Let's assume, the user clicks and chooses data from Monday to Tuesday, fast SQL and data are refreshed, then user chooses data only from the previous week, fast SQL and data are refreshed.

I would like to ask first - is it better to load sometimes very huge amount of data and then somehow just filtering them or to execute every time REST method and just refresh grid?

For the time being, the user chooses an option from the menu, I call the REST method and present data in the second activity. Now I would like to execute almost the same SQL, but with different WHERE clause, depending on the user what he wants to see.

Should I call the whole mechanism to execute the REST method or is there some library which allows me to modify SQL and "in the fly" execute REST method with different parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how large the original data is.

If the data is really big then the best option is to add filtering in the request and receive the filtered data from your backend.

In case your data is pretty much static and would probably stay the same you can fetch it all and save it to your local DB and then query it locally

but if the data is not that big you should just request it all

Anyway you should read about [Pagination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination)

The Android team also created a [paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/) as part of the architecture components

Comment: Thank you very much, pagination was the thing I was thinking of. It will be useful if user decides to get data from very long period of time.
However, there would be also situations where user can choose for example other warehouse or other type of something. Then I would have to call REST method with other parameters. 
What is my question: is there possibility somehow not to call whole mechanism for getting data from REST method, only just to modify parameters and get new data in the same transaction?

Comment: Only if your backend supports it.

Comment: If my answer helped you please upvote it and set it as approved answer